# Django looking in wrong directory for app's templates

Tags: django

App name is invitations.  I'd expect it to look in

```
$PROJECT/invitations/templates/invite_many.html
```

but instead it's looking in

```
$PROJECT/invitations/templates/invitations/invite_many.html
```

Here are the potentially relevant settings:

```
import os.path

ROOT_DIR = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..'))
PROJECT_NAME = os.path.basename(ROOT_DIR)

def ABS_PATH(*args):
    return os.path.join(ROOT_DIR, *args)

def ENV_SETTING(key, default):
    import os
    return os.environ.get(key, default)

TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
    # 'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',
)

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    ABS_PATH('templates'),
)
```

Comment: Where you are using the template in your code? if you are giving template path as `invitations/invite_many.html` you should only do `invite_many.html`

Comment: Yeah that was it.  Pretty silly mistake - just got in the habit of writing out the template path as app_name/file.html.  Go ahead and answer so I can mark it correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are giving template path as `invitations/invite_many.html` whereas you should only give `invite_many.html`